# lsort doesn't properly sort file names properly

Tags: tcl, glob

I capture a list of pictures in a repository folder like this:

```
foreach image [lsort [glob -nocomplain -directory $image_path -type f *]] {
    puts $image
}
```

All the images come back sorted because of the [`lsort`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm), but a few images simply doesn't get sorted, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

The order returned from the folder is:

```
Repository/Unsorted/3.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/30.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/33.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/6.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/9.jpg
```

**Expected**:

```
Repository/Unsorted/3.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/6.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/9.jpg 
Repository/Unsorted/30.jpg
Repository/Unsorted/33.jpg
```

**Update**:
When I use the `-dictionary` switch it returns the correct order. Can someone elaborate on why?

```
foreach image [lsort -dictionary [glob -nocomplain -directory $image_path -type f *]] {
    puts $image
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [lsort](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm) man page? It's explained quite clearly there.

Comment: @glennjackman - The problem is I have two folders of images with just numbers as file names, one set came up in the expected order, while the other (the one mentioned in my question) didn't. I can't explain it, but `-dictionary` seemed to work. On the surface it seemed just like a standard file name. Why did one set come back as expected, and the other didn't? Why was the switch necessary to sort the remaining images?

Comment: Think of it this way: if you're sorting _lexically_ (i.e. by the ASCII value of the characters), then `30` is before `6` because the ASCII value of "3" is smaller than the ASCII value of "6". The -dictionary flag adds intelligence about detecting integers within the strings (where the _number_ 6 is obviously smaller than the _number_ 30).

Comment: @glennjackman - Ah! I see. Thanks for the help. I have to go read up on ASCII values to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lsort` command has several ways in which it can decide the ordering of elements.

- `-ascii` (the default mode for various reasons, slightly misnamed) just uses the numeric ordering of each pair characters in the two strings, in the order of the characters in the string. It's the sort of thing you'd expect with the C `strcmp()`… if that was Unicode-aware.
- `-dictionary` is the same… except that digit sequences in the string (so just the characters `0` through `9`; *not* `-` so no negative numbers) are compared as numbers. This gives an ordering that feels a lot more like what you get in a dictionary; it was specifically made to produce a pleasing order of filenames in Tk's file selection dialogs.
- and, for completeness, `-integer` and `-real` parse the strings as integers and floating-point numbers respectively and then sort those, and `-command` lets you provide your own ordering command (slower, but totally gives you control).

The only reason that Tcl knows in what order to sort values is because you tell it.

Thus, when comparing `Repository/Unsorted/3.jpg` and `Repository/Unsorted/30.jpg`, in `-ascii` mode the `.` (Unicode U+00002E) comes before `0` (Unicode U+000030), whereas in `-dictionary` mode the `3` and the `30` digit sequences are parsed as integers and compared that way (because the non-numeric part before that was identical).

Comment: The order of filenames out of `glob` is basically the order that the OS's directory listing routines give us. That order definitely depends on filesystem type, also often but not always the order of creation, and who knows, maybe the phase of the moon and the colour of your socks. It's literally not defined. No duplicate names though (but if a file is in twice because of links, well, `glob` makes no attempt to detect that).